# Setting flow variables using Visualforce

Tags: flow

Can we assign value to the visual flow variables using apex controller after the flow has started.
I do not want to pass in the values intially

Comment: did you look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_intro.htm?search_text=visual ?  Question needs elaboration.